# Wowza GoCoder live streaming not working with other RTMP

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wowza

a week ago, I signed up for Wowza streaming cloud and created a live stream as RTMP. Did everything as the default(use goCoderSDK, use cloud.wowza). and it does work.

But, if I create livestream from another host in the same way, it doesnt work.

this is Code,

and The code is too long, so it's short

```
    var goCoder: WowzaGoCoder!
    var goCoderConfig:WowzaConfig!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let goCoderLicensingError = WowzaGoCoder.registerLicenseKey("GOSK-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx")

        if (goCoderLicensingError != nil) {
            print(goCoderLicensingError?.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.goCoder = WowzaGoCoder.sharedInstance()
        }

        if (self.goCoder != nil) {
            self.goCoder?.cameraView = self.view

            self.goCoder?.cameraPreview?.start()
        }
        self.goCoderConfig = self.goCoder.config
        // url
        self.goCoderConfig.hostAddress = "t-rtmp.mstone.online"
        self.goCoderConfig.portNumber = 1935
        // key
        self.goCoderConfig.applicationName = "live"
        self.goCoderConfig.streamName = "YF7yqiLRhUgyEg6htMKb"
//        self.goCoderConfig.username = "client47800"
//        self.goCoderConfig.password = "0fcc329c"
        goCoder.config = self.goCoderConfig

@IBAction func playliveButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.goCoder.startStreaming(self)
}
```

and, error here , help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJAAV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Wowza GoCoder only works with Wowza Streaming Engine or Wowza Streaming Cloud. It uses a proprietary protocol - "wowz" - to communicate with the server.

Source: https://www.wowza.com/docs/wowza-gocoder-sdk-faq#what-protocol-does-the-gocoder-sdk-use-to-broadcast-to-wowza-streaming-engine-and-wowza-streaming-cloud-